# What is the best way to write a .find query in a GET request with mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I am trying to make a GET request so that it only returns the last item stored in my database.  I can get the answer I want in the mongo shell (see below), but I'm at a loss as to how to compose the query in my GET route.  I am using ejs templates, so I will also need to pass the response through the res.render as well.  I am still kind of new to programming so forgive me if this question isn't as concise as it should be.

My mongo shell query:
`Blog.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)`

Comment: This is impossible to say without seeing your server code for the GET route. How does your server parse the URL parameter?

Comment: you can pass the `id` in `GET` request something like this `localhost:8080/mypath?id=1` and read the `id` value from `query` params. Look at sample code on `how to write a microservice` using `nodejs and expressjs`

Comment: So here is an example of how I wrote an initial request to get all items back:
```app.get("/index", (req, res) => {
  Blog.find({}, (err, allBlogs) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong:", err);
    } else {
      res.render("index", {
        blogs: allBlogs
      });
    }
  });
});```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the code below gives you a hint on how to structure your code using express and EJS.

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const blogItem = await Blog.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1);

    // Render the page with the result
    res.render("your-page.ejs", { blog: blogItem });
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors here
    res.render("500.ejs");
    throw error; 
  }
});
```